# Struggling to solve MS Access OpenForm was cancelled - error 2501

Tags: ms-access, vba

```vb
'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (recordSet.EOF And recordSet.BOF) Then
    recordSet.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit

    'See if credentials match data
    Do
        If (recordSet!User_ID = PERSAL And recordSet!Password = Password) Then

           'Open Menu form

            DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal

            recordSet.Close 'Close the recordset
            Set recordSet = Nothing 'Clean up

            'Close Login form
            DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login"

            Exit Do
        End If

        recordSet.MoveNext

        If (recordSet.EOF Or recordSet.BOF) Then
            MsgBox "Your credentials are incorrect or you are not registered."

            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    'Match the values entered for PERSAL nr. and password fields with a row in User table

Else

    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."

     recordSet.Close 'Close the recordset
     Set recordSet = Nothing 'Clean up

End If

Form_Login.txtUser_ID.SetFocus
```

I have tried every solution I've found for the past 2 days but nothing has worked to solved my error 2501:

I did:

- Decompiling
- Compact and repair
- Tackling the MSCOMCTL.OCX file
- Importing to a new access file

I am spent.

For the MSCOMCTL.OCX file I'm thinking to download a 2007 Office update SP 3.

The exception/error appears on this line:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
```

Comment: check your form open/load event. Besides, looping through employee table to find an employee is not the best practice. use sql, or dlookups

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct. Try:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal
```

Comment: There was not change.

Comment: I redid the form. There is no difference.

Comment: The error has reoccurred. I have decompiled/compact and repaired twice this today.

Comment: Create a plain new form and let your code open this. If it doesn't fail, the error is your other form; if it fails, the error is somewhere else.